# regex: Find string having different substrings

Tags: regular-expression

I want to find all strings in my code having incorrect parameters. Here is what I want to do:

find all occurrences of:

```
CreateNewPoint(CorrectPoint.X, IncorrectPoint.Y, other_parameters)
CreateNewPoint(IncorrectPoint.X, CorrectPoint.Y, other_parameters)
```

and ignore all occurrences of:

```
CreateNewPoint(CorrectPoint.X, CorrectPoint.Y, other_parameters)
```

Please note, that in my example I use `CorrectPoint` and `IncorrectPoint` variable names, but these can be anything.

I am thinking about something like:

```
CreateNewPoint(\(.*\)\.X, \1\.Y, .*)
```

but I am not interested in lines using same same variable names, but different ones.

Comment: Outside my editor I use pipes: `grep -n sourcecode 'CreateNewPoint(' | grep -v 'CreateNewPoint(\(.*\)\.X, \1\.Y,'`, but I prefer to do it inside my editor.

Comment: Welcome to the site. When asking questions about text processing, please be sure to add a minimal reproducible example of the problem - i.e. (possible anonymized) example input, desired output, what you already tried, and in which way the output you got from your attempts deviates from the expectation. That way you can avoid receiving answers that you already know won't work, and contributors can verify proposed solutions before posting them as answers.

Comment: You say you want to do it inside your editor - but you don't even mention what is the editor you're using.

Comment: My primary editor is vim, for some languages I use MS Visual Studio. My reference to editor is not about any specific editor, but if it is possible to create single regex pattern matching what I want. But if there is option how to combine two regex in vim (like I do with grep), it can help as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `grep` and using flag `-P` (*"Interpret `PATTERN` as a Perl regular expression"*), you can use **negative lookahead**.

```
grep -P 'CreateNewPoint\((.*)\.X, ((?!\b\1\b).)*\.Y, .*\)' /tmp/codefile
```

- `(?!\b\1\b)` Means that the next thing cannot be the previously matched word enclosed by word boundaries (with the `\b`, it might miss strings that **include** the first match, but are not **identical** to it.
- `((?!\b\1\b).)*` - since you also want to match the `\.Y, .*\)` afterwards, we'll need to tell `grep` to go over all the characters (and ensure they don't match the word) and then match `\.Y`.

In `vim` you can match similarly by using `/CreateNewPoint(\(.*\)\.X, \(\(\<\1\.\)\@!.\)*\.Y, .*)`. It's similar to the `grep` regex, with few exceptions:

- `\@!` is the negative lookahead identifier.
- `\<` is the beginning of the word (instead of the `\b` word boundry).
- Instead of the the word boundary at the end, we just say it cannot end with a dot `\.`.

Comment: Works like a charm. In MS Visual Studio I can use _Perl regular expression_ form. Thank you very much!